# How do you calculate Pairwise XOR?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, binary-data, xor

How is pairwise XOR calculated ? I googled but could not find anything relevant.

EDIT : How is it different from normal XOR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each bit of the number are pairwise XOR'd with each other.   For example:

```
  15 = 0000 1111
  21 = 0001 0101
```

So, the XOR is

```
       0001 1010 = 26
```

Comment: How is this different from normal XOR?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pairwise".  There's not a standard, different XOR function called "pairwise XOR" - it probably just refers to the fact that you're repeating XOR calculation among two collated sets/arrays.

If this is for a class however, all bets are off - if the prof defined "pairwise XOR", you've got to know what the definition is...

Comment: Was going through this paper and stumbled onto it : http://lanterns.eecs.utk.edu/publications/kBF_infocom.pdf

Comment: Ah.  "pairwise" there just refers to the fact that each char of the strings in question are XOR'd with the corresponding chars in the other, paired string.

So, str_a[0] with str_b[0], str_a[1] with str_b[1], etc...

Comment: Oddly enough, I was looking for a similar paper on this exact stuff but had forgotten the name of it.   So, thanks!  *lucky!* =)